# Ubuntu20.04 LTSをインストールしてもブラックアウトする

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vagrant, gpu

Ubuntu20.04ISOをダウンロードしてUSBにメディアを作ってフォーマットしたSSDにインストールしようとしたのですが、
およそ80％の確率でブートしたあと画面を表示できずブラックアウトします。
20％の確率で何故かBootモード（Ubuntu installやUbuntu safe Graphic install、Try ubuntuなどの選択肢が出てくる画面）にはたどり着け、Safe Graphicモードでインストールに進むと問題なくインストール出来るのですが、終了後、インストールメディアを取り外してリブートするとブート後に即ブラックアウトします。

```
CPU：Ryzen9 3900X
GPU：NVIDIA RTX2080ti
SSD：Crucial
```

おそらくRTXカードの問題だと思うのですが、手元に差し替えて試せる古いGPUがなく、困っています。

Dockerしか使ったことがないので想像でしかないのですが、Vagrantを使うとISOをCLIで開いてNVIDIAドライバーだけ追加してから再度ISO化してインストールメディアを作る。。。といったような事が出来たりしますでしょうか？
またはNVIDIAドライバがすでに入っているISOが配布されていたりする場所など、、何か解決法をご存知の方が入れば教えていただけると助かります。

Comment: USB からのブートで失敗するということでしょうか、それとも USB からインストールした後失敗するということでしょうか？　また、USB からブートして Try Ubuntu から立ち上げるのは上手くいきますか？

Comment: マザーボードにオンボードの GPU が載っているなら、一度 NVIDIA の GPU を取り外した上で起動するかどうか確かめることで問題の原因を切り分けられるかもしれません。

Comment: こんな記事があるようです。なにか参考になれば。[Ubuntu 20.04 LTS インストール方法（外付けドライブ用）](https://qiita.com/koba-jon/items/019a3b4eac4f60ca89c9)

Comment: @nekketsuuu コメントありがとうございます。USBブート自体は成功していますが、ブートした後の選択画面が出力出来ずにブラックアウトする場合と、Safa Graphisでインストールまで問題なく進んでその後Rebootの指示通りインストールメディアを外してRebootするとブラックアウトになります。Try Ubuntuも含め、Safe graphic以外はすべて失敗します

Comment: @nekketsuuu　AMD製のCPUはオンボードグラフィックがついてないかと思います。。

Comment: @kunif　コメントありがとうございます。特にインストール手順に問題はないですね

Comment: テキストモードでの起動はできますか？ / バージョンは違いますが、ドライバのインストール手順を解説したページがあります。 - [UbuntuにRTX2080Tiドライバーのインストール](https://krhb.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/05/17/181509)